# How to grep text and numbers between <> brackets

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I'm new to Perl and was wondering if you could help me with a query.

I am trying to grep out an exact sequence of text and numbers between <> brackets from a text file.

Here is the code:

```
open (FILE1, "file.txt") or die ("Error: File cannot be found"); 
@file1 = <FILE1>; 
@file2 = join(' ', @file1); 
my @grabJustTheHVSection = grep { $_ =~ /\<HV\>.*\<\\HV\>/s} @file2; 
close(FILE);
```

I want the array @grabJustTheHVSection to just contain the following from file1.txt: 
 
 00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000 
00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000 
 <\HV>

More sample code:

```
@file2  = join('', @file1); 
my @replace = grep { $_ =~ /\<HV>/g } @file2;
foreach $_ (@replace){
    if($_ !~ m/.PDT>/g){
    s /<HV>/<PDT>/g;
    s /<\\HV>/<\\PDT>/g;
    (print NEW $_) or die "Cant write to $new: $!";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Missing `use warnings; use strict;`. Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles. Use 3-arg open, not 2-arg open. Include `$!` and the filename in the error message. Don't use globals for no reason. `$_ =~` is redundant. `<` and `>` don't need to be escaped. Don't "parse" XML with a regex.

Comment: Welcome to SO and Perl. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: `join` returns a string; it makes no sense to store it in an array. Similarly, `grep` on a single string makes no sense: it will return either that string (if it matches), or nothing. Why do you want to store the result in an array? What would the elements be?

Comment: Did you really intend for `<\HV>` to contain a backslash, and not the X/HTML style *forward* slash `</HV>`?

Comment: I'll include more code for the task i'm trying to complete below - basically I want to search a text file, if the the text file doesn't contain a section called <PDT><\PDT> - i am attempting to take a copy of the <HV><\HV> section and rename it <PDT><\PDT>. I was attempting to use grep to extract the <HV> section into an array.

Comment: yeah <\HV> is correct

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of markup language, you should probably use a parser instead. The "reversed" backslash in `<\HV>` seems to indicate something else, but perhaps that is a typo?

Anyway, you can use the [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). The gist is that between the conditions the flip-flop returns true, otherwise false.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

chomp(my @file = <DATA>);

my @HV = grep /<HV>/ .. /<\\HV>/, @file;
print Dumper \@HV;

__DATA__
foo
<HV>
00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000
00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000
<\HV>
bar
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '<HV>',
          '00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000',
          '00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00000000 00100000',
          '<\\HV>'
        ];
```